# Accepting a dynamic table name in Postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres function that I want to make make more dynamic by exchanging the table with a variable, but apparently I get the ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$4"
How do I make it accept a dynamic table name?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.find_missing(from_id integer DEFAULT 1, to_id integer DEFAULT 10, amount integer DEFAULT 1, table_name text) 
RETURNS TABLE(id integer)
LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT s.i AS first_missing_id
FROM generate_series($1, $2) s(i)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM $4 WHERE raw_id = s.i )LIMIT $3;
$function$
```

Comment: 1) [SQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS): "SQL function arguments can only be used as data values, not as identifiers. Thus for example this is reasonable: INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($1); but this will not work: INSERT INTO $1 VALUES (42);" 2) Use `plpgsql` and its [Dynamic commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: This syntax is incorrect because `table-name` can not be a variable (or parametric value). You can use `Dynamic SQL` to solve this problem.